# parsing xml to construct a path from source to destination

Tags: python

Need a method to fetch details from a xml to construct a path from source to target.

For example:

```
<CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="col1" FROMINSTANCE ="table1"  TOFIELD ="col1" TOINSTANCE ="table4" />
<CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="col2" FROMINSTANCE ="table2"  TOFIELD ="col2" TOINSTANCE ="table3" />
<CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="col4" FROMINSTANCE ="table4"  TOFIELD ="col4" TOINSTANCE ="table2" />
```

should yield as output: `table1->table4->table2->table3`

same is with columns available in table as mapping is column level with in a table
 `table1.col1->table4.col4->table2.col2->table3.col3`

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm new to python need help to create recursive function i'm trying with xml element tree functionality